# What is the radix of a base zero and 1 number system.

Tags: number-systems

There are 2 questions:
1.What is the radix of a base zero number system?
2. What is the radix of a base 1 number system?

Answer (score 0):

- A Prisimetric is a vector valued function which represents a
  Number in Radix of Zero.
- `0` denotes no value with identity, it represents other values
- `00` denotes the value `1`.
- `000` denote the value `2`.
- `0000` denotes the value `3`.
- A prisimetric represents a point `triangulum cum basi wide` [or `with a wide base`]

You can represent unary systems of 1 as a Prisimetric with the same notion e.g.

- `11` denotes the value `1`.
- `111` denotes the value `2`.
- `1111` denotes the value `3`.

Thus they can also represent binary systems and exist within them at the same time.

See also
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit